# 'NCD.L1.sample--Communite' couldn't addNewComplaint() due to invalid characters for account ID

Tags: nearprotocol

The repo is here: 
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--Communite

As I was testing the app I was trying to add a complaint entry, but the `--account-id` seem to have a problem. I have also tried `--account_id` and `--accountId` but none of that worked so far.

[image: The error]

Did I miss anything? Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Target contract you are trying to call is not specified in the command. Check the arguments:

```
❯ near call
near call <contractName> <methodName> [args]

schedule smart contract call which can modify state
```

- first argument after `call` is the name of the contract you are trying to call,
- second argument is the name of the method on that contract to be called,
- third argument is the payload.

`--accountId` is used to specify the signer of the txs.

So basically, from the README on the screenshot you are missing the field `<your deployed contract>`.